A question about smoothing lemma and proof
I'm a beginner on lattice-based cryptography and currently reading a handout of Prof. Vinod Vaikuntanathan.
The first question
In section 2.4 Smoothing Lemma and Proof, I cannot figure out why the second equality is hold:

I think it may by the fact of $\hat{\phi}_s(\mathbf{y})=1/s^n\cdot\hat{\rho}_s(\mathbf{y}+\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))$ and the linearity of the Fourier transform $\hat{\rho}_s(\mathbf{y}+\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))=\hat{\rho}_s(\mathbf{y})\cdot\hat{\rho}_s(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))$? Then, we can rearrange the formula as $\hat{\rho}_s(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))\cdot(1/s^n)\sum_{\mathbf{y}\in\mathcal{L}^*}\hat{\rho}_s(\mathbf{y})e^{2\pi i\langle\mathbf{x,y}\rangle}$.
So how do we know that $\hat{\rho}_s(\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B}))=\det(\mathcal{L}^*)$?
The second question

I think there is a typo.
Shouldn't we swap the third equal sign and the fourth inequality sign?

First Question:
As you mention, it suffices to show that
$$
\hat{\phi}_s(y) = \det(L^*) (1/s^n)\hat{\rho}_s(y).
$$
We know that
$$
\phi_s(y) = (1/s^n)\sum_{z\in L} \rho_s(y+z)
$$
The fact that this implies the desired identity then follows from (the equality proved in) Lemma 8 of your handout.
Second Question:
I think both symbols should be $\leq$ actually.
The first is from bounding the average by the maximum, e.g. $\int_S f(x) \leq \max_{x\in S} f(x)$ for any (integrable) function $f$.
The second is a little more involved, in particular we show that
$$
|\sum_y \rho(y)\exp(2\pi i\langle x, y\rangle| \leq \sum_y \rho(y) |\exp(2\pi i\langle x, y\rangle| = \sum_y \rho(y)
$$
is upper bounded independently of $x$, so taking the maximum over $x$ yields the desired inequality.
Both arguments seem to only give bounds $\leq$, not $=$, though.
